# Hide Android softkeys (triangle, circle, rectangle shape) when it appears automatically in Delphi FMX

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, android-softkeyboard

I set my form on MyApp as a FullScreen. So it means the form will cover all area of Android screen including softkey (In currently android phone) and Info Bar (Battery, simcard, signal info etc). Unfortunately, MyApp uses some default dialog bog comes with fmx (TDialogService.MessageDialog) and it will trigger device to show softkey, and it wont hide automatically when dialog box closed.

I tried to hide virtual keyboard by adding new procedure like this :

```
procedure TForm1.HideSoftKeyAndVKeyboard;
var FService: IFMXVirtualKeyboardService;
begin
  TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService
      (IFMXVirtualKeyboardService, IInterface(FService));
  FService.HideVirtualKeyboard;
end;
```

But the softkey, is still there.

Do you have any solution for this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: How did you set your app to fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, especially after anonymous thread.
For me working this

```
uses Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNIBridge, Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, FMX.Helpers.Android, Androidapi.Helpers;
```

and after dialog end or Thread termination this

```
var
uiOptions: Integer;
begin
uiOptions := SharedActivity.getWindow.getDecorView.getSystemUiVisibility;
SharedActivity.getWindow.getDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            TJView.JavaClass.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or TJView.JavaClass.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or TJView.JavaClass.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or TJView.JavaClass.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            or TJView.JavaClass.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            or 2048); // SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE = 2048
end;
```